# If SMB can share serial ports, does that apply to USB Ports as well?

Tags: usb, smb, serial-port

I was just taking a course and they said something I never heard of, that serial ports can be shared over SMB.

That sounded kind of strange to me, but I guess I've never had a need to share a serial port.

USB (Universal **Serial** Bus) is in someway tied to serial ports, so that got me wondering can SMB share serial ports as well?

Comment: USB has very little to do with serial ports, their only link, is that USB is data is serial.  How the host client communication is initiate is completely different.  Can you share the relevant course material as it’s written exactly?  USB clients communicate with a single USB host.  I am not aware of any solution to share a USB device that doesn’t involve another protocol (I.e TCP networking packets).  USB switches work since the host is physical switched.

Comment: @Ramhound From: https://www.udemy.com/course/linux-raid-lvm-management/learn/lecture/10219984 `SMB is used for sharing files, printers, and serial ports and the port number is 445 (Directly over TCP).`

Comment: So Windows is sharing a serial device connected to it through SMB.  You can share specific type of USB devices, like a printer, or share files on a storage USB storage device but wouldn’t be able to share that physical storage device (attach it to the remote host).  You can’t share a USB keyboard or mouse for instance through SMB.

Comment: @Ramhound I still feel like there’s something here about sharing a device over serial port, but I’ve never seen it done, since you just don’t see much in the way of serial devices anymore unless they’re attached via a USB port to serial converter.

Comment: Printers for the longest time were connected with a serial port.  This allowed earlier versions of Windows to share a printer.  Before USB came to be this allowed a printer server to exist on a network.  This was probably Windows 2000 and Windows 98 era network sharing.

Comment: @Ramhound And zip / jazz drives.

Comment: I only saw that implementation in Sun hardware and that was a literal serial network (Device A -> Client A -> Client B) but never looked under the hood on that specific hardware since it was fragile has heck.

Comment: @leeand00 Zip and Jazz drives where never serial as far as I remember (too slow). Zip used floppy controller, parallel or USB and later IDE as well. Jazz was in my memory only USB, IDE and SCSI.
Both drives where actually SCSI drives (device type Magneto Optical) internally. Which made USB ans SCSI interfaces easy. And the parallel driver for the Zip was actually a SCSI over parallel driver (very similar to the one that HP used for a lot of their printers/scanners that were internally SCSI as well.)

Comment: @Tonny yeah you’re right, cause parallel ports were wide and had more pins than a serial port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SMB can, in theory, share serial (aka COM) ports.
Most people don't know that, but it is true.
However, that particular use-case is extremely rare. In my 30+ years in the computer industry I have never seen (or even heard of) that actually being used in real life.
As far as a I know most SMB implementations (including Microsoft and Samba) don't actually implement that feature.

As for the other part of your question:
USB isn't reallya serial port. A serial port (aka COM-port) is only one of (many) type of devices can that can be connected to the USB bus.
The word serial in USB just means that the data over a USB cable is transmitted serially (as opposed to parallel). Logically speaking USB is a totally different (and much more complicated) thing than a simple COM-port. It is both the hardware specification for the USB bus hardware and the protocol specification for the USB software protocols running on top of that hardware.

In the same manner as USB you could also say that ethernet, SATA and PCie are "serial" protocols as these also transmit serially. (The S in SATA even stands for Serial as well.) PCIe is even more interesting because if defines a bus consisting of multiple serial links used together in parallel.